# Why does Solve work in v9.0.1 but not in v10.3.1

Tags: equation-solving, backslide

I want to solve the following DE 
$$ P'=k(M-P)P, P[0]=53.08, P[50]=23.192, P[100]=76.212.$$
The Mathematica command is

```
sol1 = DSolve[P'[t] == k (M - P[t]) P[t], P[t], t]

P[t_] = sol1[[1,1,2]]

sol2 = Solve[{P[0]==5.308,P[50]==23.192,P[100]==76.212}, {C[1],k,M}]
```

*Mathematica 10.3.1* can't solve it:

[image]

but *9.0.1* can:

[image]

I do not know why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your DE says $P' = k(M - P)$ but your input to `DSolve` is equivalent to $P' = k(M - P) P$

Comment: @JasonB, it was a typo. I changed. Thanks.

Comment: Try `Reduce` instead.

Comment: Don't use uninformative titles... ones that do not help anyone search and find the answer.

Comment: @xpaul, pay attention, mathematica is not already stable. It can be a bug. I have reported some bugs on 10.3. on Mac os x

Comment: It works in V11.2.  Did you try rationalizing it yourself, as the error message recommended?

Comment: @MichaelE2, I do not have V11.

Comment: More importantly, what about rationalizing the coefficients and using V10.3.1?  (See `Rationalize` in the docs, or do it by hand since there are only three.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, I will try. Thank you.